Proof that $a_i^T x = 0$ for linearly independent vectors $a_i$ implies $x = 0$
Let $n \geq 0$.
Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots a_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be linearly independent vectors.
I want to prove the following statements:
If there exists a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a_i^T x = 0$ for all $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots n$, then $x = 0$.
How to prove this?
My Attempt:
Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_1^T \\ a_2^T \\ a_3^T \\ \ldots \\ a_n^T \end{pmatrix}$.
Given condition that $a_i^T x = 0$ for all $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots n$, we have $A x = 0$.
Since the vectors $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots a_n$ are linearly independent, the matrix $A$ is full rank.
Therefore, $A x = 0$ implies $x = A^{-1} 0 = 0$.
Comments:
I believe the statement is intuitively true because the vectors are linearly independent. However, I feel my proof is a bit roundabout. Are there more elegant or sophisticated ways to prove this?

Since there are $n$ li. vectors $a_k$, they span $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so there are scalars $x_k$ such that $x = \sum_k x_k a_k$, and $|x|^2 = x^Tx = \sum_k x_k a_k^T x = 0$.

@copper.hat Thank you very much for your comment. I appreciate the idea of multiplying another $x$, which I hadn't thought of.

Your proof is correct but I think a proof by contradiction, not using any knowledge about matrices, is more appropriate here. Something like: suppose $x\neq 0$. Then we will prove that $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n,x$ are l. i., which is a contradiction. Indeed, assume you have
$$
\lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2+\dots\lambda_na_n+\mu x=0.
$$
If you dot multiply by $x$ you get $\mu x\cdot x=0$. Since $x\neq 0$ you obtain $\mu=0$. But then all of the $\lambda_i$ are also zero given that the $a_i$ are linearly independent. Conclusion: $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\dots=\lambda_n=\mu=0$ and the vectors $a_1,a_2,\dots a_n,x$ are l.i., contradicting the fact that the dimension is $n$.

Thank you very much for your answer. I hadn't considered using the fact that $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, x$ are linearly independent to derive a contradiction. Great idea!
